# Validate a field: required_if the url contains parameter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules, laravel-validation

Is there any way to validate required field when the requested url contains some parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Form requsts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation), you can simple use PHP condition.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = []; // here you put some rules

    // here you check condition and add some rule when it's true
    if (str_contains($this->input('url'), 'something')) {
       $rules['some_other_field'] = 'required';

    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check the route before validating....

```
$roles =[
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
];

if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath() == "xxxxx"){
    $role['desc'] = 'required'
}

if(\Request::route()->getName() == "yyyy"){
    $role['desc'] = 'required'
}

if($request->is('admin/*')){
    $role['desc'] = 'required'
}

$this->validate($request, $role);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the field anyway, but not as required, you can use

```php
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'desc' => [
                Rule::requiredIf(fn() => !empty($this->route('parameter'))),
             ]
        ];
    }
```